# TFS: batch updating of work items in web version of TeamExporer

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

In the web version of team explorer I've selected few work items (they are pretty similar: same type, assigned to me, are in same state). When I selected them and clicked "Edit Work Items" new window appeared with text:

> State  (*) cannot change the state
>   (*) To change the state or reason, selected work items must be of the same type and state

What is wrong in my case? Those items are of the same type and state. Why I can't update them?

Thanks.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more information. I should point out that you can't "bypass" a state transition that's required by your work item type. For example, you probably can't move a bug directly from "Active" to "Closed" without first setting its state to "Resolved."

Comment: That is fine: I don't plan to break rules and will switch from 'Active' to 'Resolved' only. More over, for items in 'Active' state during batch update I would expect to see only 'Resolved' state as possible new... But in my case it can't change state at all!